# Find Probability Density Function: Divergent Integral

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, density-function

This is Problem 6.10 in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer.

***Problem Statement:*** In a process of sintering (heating) two types of copper powder the
density function for $Y_1,$ the volume proportion of solid copper in a sample, is given by
$$f_1(y_1)=
\begin{cases}
6y_1(1-y_1),&0\le y_1\le 1\\
0,&\text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
$$
The density function for $Y_2,$ the proportion of type $A$ crystals among the solid copper, is
given as
$$f_2(y_2)=
\begin{cases}
3y_2^2,&0\le y_2\le 1\\
0,&\text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
$$
The variable $U=Y_1Y_2$ gives the proportion of the sample volume due to type $A$ crystals. If $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, find the probability density function for $U.$

***My Work So Far:*** Since the variables are independent by assumption, the joint density function is
$$f(y_1,y_2)=
\begin{cases}
18y_1y_2^2(1-y_1),&0\le y_1,y_2\le 1\\
0,&\text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
$$
Now then, we have
\begin{align*}
F_U(u)
&=P(U\le u)\\
&=P(Y_1Y_2\le u)\\
&=P(Y_1\le u/Y_2)\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{u/y_2}18y_1y_2^2(1-y_1)\,dy_1\,dy_2.
\end{align*}

***My Question:*** The problem is that the integral in my last line does not converge, no-how, no-way. I've tried reversing the order of integration, to no avail. Am I missing something basic?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: *Invariably* the solution to problems of this nature is to incorporate the domains explicitly.  In other words, the integrand *must* be multiplied by $\mathscr{I}(0\le y_1,y_2\le 1).$ Equivalently, $u/y_2$ must be replaced by $\min(1,u/y_2).$ As always, it helps to draw a picture of the domain of integration.

Comment: Great, thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From whuber's suggestion, after drawing a picture of the region of integration, the proper limits are:
\begin{align*}
F_U(u)
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{\min(1,\,u/y_2)}18y_1y_2^2(1-y_1)\,dy_1\,dy_2\\
&=\int_u^1\int_0^{u/y_2}18y_1y_2^2(1-y_1)\,dy_1\,dy_2+\int_0^u\int_0^118y_1y_2^2(1-y_1)\,dy_1\,dy_2\\
&=\int_u^1\left(9u^2-\frac{6u^3}{y_2}\right)dy_2+\int_0^u 3y_2^2\,dy_2\\
&=\left(3u^2(3y_2-2u\ln(y_2))\right)\big|_u^1+u^3\\
&=9u^2-3u^2(3u-2u\ln(u))+u^3\\
&=u^2(9-8u+6u\ln(u))\\
f_U(u)&=18u(1-u+u\ln(u)).
\end{align*}
And of course you have to set up the limits, and build a case structure.